# Print all the possible shortest paths in a graph

Tags: c, dijkstra

I'm writing some code to print all the possible shortest paths in a graph using a modified version of Dijkstra's algorithm. While in the classic implementation you have an array in which you store the predecessor of each node, I created a matrix in which you can have multiple predecessors for each node, so that you can follow more than one path from a node to the source. 
The problem is, I just can't figure out how to print it. I wrote this code, but it does not provide the correct solution:

```
void print(graph grf, int node) {
    int n;
    if (grf->preds[node][0] == NIL) {
        printf("\n%i", node);
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (n = 0; n<grf->number; n++) {
            if (grf->preds[node][n] != NIL) {
                print(grf, grf->preds[node][n]);
                printf("->%i", node);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It prints the following solution:

```
1->0
1->9->8
1->3->7
1->0->7->8->2
1->3
1->9->4
1->3->5
1->0->5
1->3->7
1->0->7->6
1->9->8
1->3->7
1->0->7->8->6
1->3->7
1->0->7
1->9->8
1->3->7
1->0->7->8
1->9
```

While this is the correct one (please note that the order is not important):

```
1->9
1->9->8
1->9->8->6
1->9->8->2
1->9->4
1->3
1->3->7
1->3->7->8
1->3->7->8->6
1->3->7->8->2
1->3->7->6
1->3->5
1->0
1->0->7
1->0->7->8
1->0->7->8->6
1->0->7->8->2
1->0->7->6
1->0->5
```

I think this is because the for cycle calls again the function when you have two possible predecessors and you are coming back from another call, but I don't know how to avoid this and still have a simple and good working code.

One suggestion I had is to use a BFS or DFS to print the paths, but I haven't understood how.

Comment: i also did Dijkstra's algorithm but that was linked list based. its not full code and how you are giving input its also not available. Can you show us full code.

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://pastebin.com/SMVRJM1F). I didn't pasted it here beacuse it's very long. There are some parts of the code which are not used for this purpose. I use an adjacency matrix.

Comment: also, this is my input: [link](http://pastebin.com/ykkiMFFB).

Comment: better try with GDB and use debugger so that you can track where exactly you are missing.

Comment: I know where the error is, but I don't know how to solve it. since there is a cycle and inside it there is the function call, when the recursion reach the limit, it does not return straight to the starting point, but instead it takes another path to reach again the final point, while it should start again from the beginning without taking the prevoious route.

Comment: It seems odd to have have paths of length 2, 3, 4 and 5 all being listed as 'shortest'.  Unless there's a weighting factor that's not visible, a path of length 5 cannot be shortest when there's also a path of length 2, can there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is insufficient information in the question to diagnose the problem and therefore it is unlikely to be of benefit to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if anyone is interested I solved the problem. I created a temporary array in which I store the path, and when the function reachs the ending point, it prints all the array. There is a variable which is incremented at each call, which stores the depth of the recursion and says to the function in which position of the array store the node.
Here is the code:

```
void stampa(p_grafo grf, int nodo, int depth) {
int contatore, i;
if (grf->preds[nodo][0] == NIL) {
    printf("%i", nodo);
    for(i=grf->numero-1;i>=0;i--)
        if(grf->temp[i]!=NIL)
            printf("->%i", grf->temp[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
else {
    for (contatore = 0; contatore<grf->numero; contatore++) {
        if (grf->preds[nodo][contatore] != NIL) {
            grf->temp[depth]=nodo;
            stampa(grf, grf->preds[nodo][contatore], depth+1);
        }
    }
}
return;
}
```